Probability of labelled Red and Blue cards

A. We have a pack of 12 red cards labelled 1-12 and a pack of 12 blue cards labelled 1-12. We randomly remove 2 cards from the blue pack, shuffle all 22 remaining cards together and draw one at random. It is a 3. What is the probability that it's blue?


B. We have a pack of 12 red cards labelled 1-12 and a pack of 10 blue cards labelled 1-10. We shuffle all of the cards together and draw one at random. It is a 3. What is the probability that it's blue?


C. We have a pack of 12 red cards labelled 1-12 and a pack of 10 blue cards labelled 1-10. We randomly choose 3 cards from each of the red pack and the blue pack, shuffle all 6 of these cards together and draw one at random. It is a 3. What is the probability that it's blue?

Can't find the solutions to these online. Here are my answers:
A) P(choosing a blue card) is independent of its rank, therefore, P(B|3) = P(B) = 5/11
B) Using the same logic as (A), P(B|3) = P(B) = 5/11
(C) Let B be event of picking a blue card, and R be the event pf picking a red card,
$$P(B|3) = \frac{P(3|B) \cdot P(B)}{P(3|B) \cdot P(B) + P(3|R) \cdot P(R)} \tag{(1)}$$
$$P(3|B) = P(3|B, \text{ 3B was picked among 10 cards}) \cdot P(\text{3B was picked among 10 cards})$$
$$= \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)$$
Similarly,
$$P(3|R) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{12}\right)$$
Plugging these into equation (1):
$$P(B|3) = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{30}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{30}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{36}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
$$= \frac{6}{11}$$
Does this seem right?

For b. Note that the difference in the decks breaks the symmetry between the ranks. Now,  a 3 is more likely to be chosen than a 12.

For b, you have one red 3 and one blue 3, with the same probability of drawing each one

Oh, my bad. I apologize for this silly error.

For part (c), in calculating the P(3|B) part. Is the P(3|B, 3B was pick among 10 cards) = 1/3 or 1/6. I am quite confused now.

You can learn some MathJax to format your math expressions/ formulas, see here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

The unformatted computation is hard to read.  For $c$, the probability of drawing $3R$ is $\frac 3{12}\times \frac 16=\frac 1{24}$.  The probability of drawing $3B$ is $\frac 3{10}\times \frac 16=\frac 1{20}$.  By Bayes, given that you got a $3$, the probability that it was $3B$ is $\frac 1{20}\big / \left(\frac 1{20}+\frac 1{24}\right)=\frac 6{11}$ which at least confirms your result.

Apologies for that. I have updated the text. Please read it now. Is my approach right?

@lulu In your last comment, concerning part c, aren't you overlooking the (mutually exclusive) possibilities that either none of the three red cards is a 3, or none of the three blue cards is a 3?

@user2661923  No...the probability that you draw $3R$, say,  is determined in two steps.  First, $3R$ must be one of the three chosen from the Red Deck (Prob. $\frac 3{12}$) and then it must be selected from the $6$ ($\frac 16$).  Multiplying gives you the desired result.  As a sanity check note that all Red cards should have the same probability, $\frac 1{24}$  and all Blue cards should have probability $\frac 1{20}$ and $12\times \frac 1{24}+10\times \frac 1{20}=1$.

@lulu See part c of my answer.  I used a different approach but got the same answer.  What concerned me was when computing the probability of drawing a $~3~$ (i.e. the denominator) you have to give twice the weight to the event that the three red cards and three blue cards each include a $~3.$  Initially, I wasn't sure that any other approach is valid.  Having just read your last comment, I agree with your logic.

The reason that I posted this answer is that I used a different approach for part c.  Initially, I wasn't sure whether any other approach for part c is valid.
After I posted my answer, and then read lulu's last comment, I then realized that the alternate part c approach that lulu suggests is also valid.

I will follow the model in this conditional probability article,
that $~\displaystyle p(~R ~| ~S ~) = \frac{p(~R \cap S ~)}{p(S)}.$


A. We have a pack of 12 red cards labelled 1-12 and a pack of 12 blue cards labelled 1-12. We randomly remove 2 cards from the blue pack, shuffle all 22 remaining cards together and draw one at random. It is a 3. What is the probability that it's blue?

Let $~A_1~$ denote the event that the two blue removed cards include the blue $~3.~$
Let $~A_2~$ denote the event that the two blue removed cards do not include the blue $~3.~$
Let $~R~$ denote the event that the random card is blue.
Let $~S~$ denote the event that the random card is a $~3.~$
Then
$$\frac{p(~R \cap S ~)}{p(S)} = 
\frac{p (~A_2 \cap R \cap ~S ~) + p (~A_1 \cap R \cap ~S ~)}{p (~A_2 \cap ~S ~) + p(~A_1 \cap S ~)}
$$
$$= \frac{( ~5/6 \times 1/22 ~) + (0)}{( ~5/6 \times 2/22 ~) + ( ~1/6 \times 1/22 ~)} = \frac{5/6}{11/6} = \frac{5}{11}.
$$


B. We have a pack of 12 red cards labelled 1-12 and a pack of 10 blue cards labelled 1-10. We shuffle all of the cards together and draw one at random. It is a 3. What is the probability that it's blue?

Let $~R~$ denote the event that the random card is blue.
Let $~S~$ denote the event that the random card is a $~3.~$
Then
$$\frac{p(~R \cap S ~)}{p(S)} 
= \frac{1/22}{1/22 + 1/22} = \frac{1}{2}.
$$


C. We have a pack of 12 red cards labelled 1-12 and a pack of 10 blue cards labelled 1-10. We randomly choose 3 cards from each of the red pack and the blue pack, shuffle all 6 of these cards together and draw one at random. It is a 3. What is the probability that it's blue?

Let $~A_1~$ denote the event that the three blue cards do include the blue $~3,~$ and the three red cards do include the red $~3.$
Let $~A_2~$ denote the event that the three blue cards do include the blue $~3,~$ and the three red cards do not include the red $~3.$
Let $~A_3~$ denote the event that the three blue cards do not include the blue $~3,~$ and the three red cards do include the red $~3.$
Let $~A_4~$ denote the event that the three blue cards do not include the blue $~3,~$ and the three red cards do not include the red $~3.$
Let $~R~$ denote the event that the random card is blue.
Let $~S~$ denote the event that the random card is a $~3.~$
Then
$$p( ~R \cap S ~) $$
$$= p( ~A_1 \cap R \cap S ~)
+ p( ~A_2 \cap R \cap S ~) \\ + p( ~A_3 \cap R \cap S ~)
+ p( ~A_4 \cap R \cap S ~) $$
$$= (3/10 \times 1/4 \times 1/6)
+ (3/10 \times 3/4 \times 1/6)\\
+ (0) + (0) \\= \frac{12}{10 \times 4 \times 6}.$$ 
$$p( ~S ~) $$
$$= p( ~A_1 \cap S ~)
+ p( ~A_2 \cap S ~) \\+ p( ~A_3 \cap S ~)
+ p( ~A_4 \cap S ~) $$
$$= (3/10 \times 1/4 \times 2/6)
+ (3/10 \times 3/4 \times 1/6) \\
+ (7/10 \times 1/4 \times 1/6) + (0) \\= \frac{22}{10 \times 4 \times 6}.$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{p(~R \cap S ~)}{p(S)} = \frac{12}{10 \times 4 \times 6} \div \frac{22}{10 \times 4 \times 6} = \frac{6}{11}.$$

For the first and second questions:
$P(H|E) = \frac{P(E|H)P(H)}{P(E|H)P(H) + P(E|\neg{H})P(\neg{H})}$
As R is $\neg B$, we have
$P(B|3) = \frac{P(3|B)P(B)}{P(3|B)P(B) + P(3|R)P(R)} =  \frac{\frac{1}{10}\,\frac{10}{22}}{\frac{1}{10}\,\frac{10}{22} + \frac{1}{12}\,\frac{12}{22}} = \frac{1}{2}$
This is what we would expect - there are only two threes, so the chance of either red or blue given that a three has been drawn is identical.
For the last question:
$P(B|3) = \frac{P(3|B)P(B)}{P(3|B)P(B) + P(3|R)P(R)} =  \frac{\frac{1}{10}\,\frac{3}{6}}{\frac{1}{10}\,\frac{3}{6} + \frac{1}{12}\,\frac{3}{6}} = \frac{\frac{1}{10}}{\frac{12}{120}\; + \frac{10}{120}} = \frac{12}{22}  = \frac{6}{11}$
as @lulu said.

Okay, so P(3|B) = 1/10. Can you tell me why it isn't 1/22, since we are considering the whole deck right?

@ShsTht  There is one 3 among the ten Blue cards, so the probability of a card being 3 given it was blue is 1/10.

$A$ : Correctly reasoned.  $\mathsf P_1(B\mid n)$ would be the same for each rank $n$, so we have independence; and the probability for picking a blue card is $5/11$.
$B$ : No, since we are specifically excluding ranks 11 and 12 of the blue cards, the above does not apply.  Instead, since every card is equally likely to be picked, and of the two 3, one is blue, we have:$$\mathsf P_2(B\mid 3)=\dfrac{\mathsf P_2(3, B)}{\mathsf P_2(3, B)+\mathsf P_2(3, R)}=\dfrac 12$$
$C$ : Much the same as above, but with the extra step meaning every card will not be equally likely to be picked, but rather the two colours are, so:
$$\mathsf P_3(B\mid 3)=\dfrac{\mathsf P_3(3\mid B)}{\mathsf P_3(3\mid B)+\mathsf P_3(3\mid R)}=\dfrac {1/10}{1/10+1/12}=\dfrac{6}{11}$$
